# Memory pool for object with different size - C#

Tags: c#, memory, garbage-collection, memory-pool

Do you have some solution, how to make object pool (**memory pool**) with objects than can contain different **data with different size** ? So if I request for object in memory pool with some size, it returns to me some allocated memory chunk with the closest size to my request. It should be written in **C#**. Thank you, because I really dont exactly know, what is the best collection for this and best algorithm. In C++ there are some solutions but there is no memory pool for C#.

Comment: That is because you don't need it... In C#, memory management is handled by the CLR. Or, in your case, why would you need to do explicit memory management?

Comment: What do you need it for? If I remember correctly, memory pools are used to avoid heap fragmentation. In C# the garbage collection is supposed to take care of those things, so you wouldn't need it.

Comment: Yes I know, I have to write Comunication library, which allows client to communicate with server (through specific own protocol) , client (or multiple clients) sends data to server , and data are in form of messages (string) + data (different size and format) . But this communication can run two or three weeks without interruption, so it can send thousands of messages with data during the time of communication. My boss told me, that he thinks, Garbage Collection isn't good enough for this purpose, I should write Memory Pool. But in this area, I have no skills (memory chunks and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Net Framework already has such an implementation (used by Windows Communication Foundation). See [BufferManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.buffermanager.aspx)

```
var buffMgr = BufferManager.CreateBufferManager(
                 104857600, // use no more than 100 MB in total
                 10485760);  // allocate 10 MB max to each buffer
var buff = buffMgr.TakeBuffer(65535); // allocate a buffer enough to fit a 65 KB object
                           // note: this could return a buffer bigger than 65 KB 

//when done with the buffer:
buffMgr.ReturnBuffer(buff);
```

Comment: Thank you! It seems to be what Im looking for